# ¿como puedo agregar una lista a una pregunta por teclado en el bucle while en python?

Tags: python, lista, while, diccionarios, input

Lo dicho, recién estoy empezando a aprender a programar y estoy creando un programa donde pregunto por teclado al usuario que indique un producto de una lista. Pero al poner un bucle while examinando lo que pregunto, quiero compararlo con los productos en la lista, si no sale ese producto que le de error.No consigo efectuarlo, comparo lo preguntado por teclado con mi lista y me da error. Gracias.

Comment: TIenes que incluir tu código en la pregunta. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar el código fuente (no una foto de la pantalla).

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo de solución sería el siguiente:

```py
products = ["Manzana", "Pera", "Manzana"]

# Bucle infinito hasta que se ejecute "break"
while True:
    # Se bloquea el programa hasta que el usuario introduzca
    # un valor y presione la tecla Enter. El valor se almacena
    # como un string (str) en la variable "p".
    p = input("Introduce un producto: ")
    
    if p in products:
        print("Producto encontrado")
        break  # Esto termina el bucle
    else:
        print("Producto no encontrado")
```

Ten en cuenta que la expresión `p in products` devuelve `True` si ***products*** tiene al menos 1 elemento cuyo valor es exactamente el valor de ***p*** y devuelve `False` en caso contrario. Por ejemplo, el valor "Naranja" está en ***products*** pero el valor "naranja" (con todas las letras en minúscula) no está.